# WebView can't scroll down in SwipeRefreshLayout

Tags: java, android, android-webview

I have a webview and want it to be able refresh went i swipe it. It works and can refresh the page. But the problem is when I scroll down the page, it always trigger to refresh not to go upper page. This is my Activity.java

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    private WebView mWebView;
    private static final String TAG = MainActivity.class.getSimpleName();
    public SwipeRefreshLayout swipeRefreshLayout;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        mWebView = findViewById(R.id.activity_main_webview);
        WebSettings webSettings = mWebView.getSettings();
        webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        mWebView.setWebViewClient(new MyWebViewClient());
        swipeRefreshLayout = (SwipeRefreshLayout)this.findViewById(R.id.swipe);
        mWebView.loadUrl("https://hkmu.comercio.co.id");
...
        mWebView.getViewTreeObserver().addOnScrollChangedListener(new ViewTreeObserver.OnScrollChangedListener() {
            @Override
            public void onScrollChanged() {
                if(mWebView.getScrollY()==0){
                    swipeRefreshLayout.setEnabled(true);
                }else{
                    swipeRefreshLayout.setEnabled(false);
                }
            }
        }); 

        swipeRefreshLayout.setOnRefreshListener(new SwipeRefreshLayout.OnRefreshListener() {
            @Override
            public void onRefresh() {
                swipeRefreshLayout.setRefreshing(true);
                new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        swipeRefreshLayout.setRefreshing(false);
                        mWebView.reload();
                    }
                }, 2000);
            }
        });
        swipeRefreshLayout.setColorSchemeColors(
                getResources().getColor(android.R.color.holo_blue_dark),
                getResources().getColor(android.R.color.holo_orange_dark),
                getResources().getColor(android.R.color.holo_green_dark),
                getResources().getColor(android.R.color.holo_red_dark)
        );
```

and this is my activity_main.xml

```
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">
    <androidx.swiperefreshlayout.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout
        android:id="@+id/swipe"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">
        <WebView
            android:id="@+id/activity_main_webview"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent" />
    </androidx.swiperefreshlayout.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

I know maybe my question is duplicate, I've already search it but I'm still stucked and those answer doesn't work for me

## EDIT 1

I'm already change my code like this

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    private WebView mWebView;
    private static final String TAG = MainActivity.class.getSimpleName();
    public SwipeRefreshLayout swipeRefreshLayout;
    private ViewTreeObserver.OnScrollChangedListener mOnScrollChangedListener;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        mWebView = findViewById(R.id.activity_main_webview);
        WebSettings webSettings = mWebView.getSettings();
        webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        mWebView.setWebViewClient(new MyWebViewClient());
        swipeRefreshLayout = (SwipeRefreshLayout)this.findViewById(R.id.swipe);
        mWebView.loadUrl("https://hkmu.comercio.co.id");
...
        swipeRefreshLayout.setOnRefreshListener(new SwipeRefreshLayout.OnRefreshListener() {
            @Override
            public void onRefresh() {
                swipeRefreshLayout.setRefreshing(true);
                new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        swipeRefreshLayout.setRefreshing(false);
                        mWebView.reload();
                    }
                }, 2000);
            }
        });
        swipeRefreshLayout.setColorSchemeColors(
                getResources().getColor(android.R.color.holo_blue_dark),
                getResources().getColor(android.R.color.holo_orange_dark),
                getResources().getColor(android.R.color.holo_green_dark),
                getResources().getColor(android.R.color.holo_red_dark)
        );
        @Override
        public void onStart() {
            super.onStart();

            swipeRefreshLayout.getViewTreeObserver().addOnScrollChangedListener(mOnScrollChangedListener =
                new ViewTreeObserver.OnScrollChangedListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onScrollChanged() {
                        if (mWebView.getScrollY() == -1)
                            swipeRefreshLayout.setEnabled(true);
                        else
                            swipeRefreshLayout.setEnabled(false);

                    }
                });
            swipeRefreshLayout.getViewTreeObserver().addOnScrollChangedListener(mOnScrollChangedListener);
        }

        @Override
        public void onStop() {
        swipeRefreshLayout.getViewTreeObserver().removeOnScrollChangedListener(mOnScrollChangedListener);
        super.onStop();
        }
```

It works on some website, but in my web that based on Odoo it still can't work

Answer (score 0):

I think this code will help you to solve your problems.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.swiperefreshlayout.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout
     android:id="@+id/swipe"
     android:layout_width="match_parent"
     android:layout_height="match_parent">
<androidx.core.widget.NestedScrollView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">
        <WebView
            android:id="@+id/activity_main_webview"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent" />
</LinearLayout>
</androidx.core.widget.NestedScrollView>
</androidx.swiperefreshlayout.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout>
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but it didn't work.. when use NestedScrollView my apps just show white screen and my web didn't show

Comment: i just edit my answer. please try again and let me know.